# How can I increment a column by one in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need help writing a MySQL trigger.

Suppose you have a student database with the following tables:

```
ENROLLMENT(SSN, CLASS_NO, GRADE)
CLASS(CLASS_NO, CLASS_TITLE, NO_OF_STUDENTS).
```

I need to write a trigger to increase the `NO_OF_STUDENTS` by one if a new student is added to the `ENROLLMENT` table for that `CLASS_NO`.

Comment: Could you not use a count() on the enrollment table whenever you needed the number? adding a field controlled by triggers to track that number seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use mysql trigger to do this. Try something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'database_name'.'after_insert_enrollment' AFTER INSERT ON 'ENROLLMENT' 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE class SET NO_OF_STUDENTS = NO_OF_STUDENTS +1 WHERE CLASS_NO = NEW.CLASS_NO;
END
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd also decrease `no_of_studens` in case an enrollment is deleted.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER_INS_ENROLLMENT AFTER INSERT ON ENROLLMENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE CLASS SET NO_OF_STUDENTS = NO_OF_STUDENTS + 1 WHERE CLASS_NO = NEW.CLASS_NO;
END;//
delimiter;

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER_INS_ENROLLMENT AFTER DELETE ON ENROLLMENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE CLASS SET NO_OF_STUDENTS = NO_OF_STUDENTS - 1 WHERE CLASS_NO = NEW.CLASS_NO;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: delete trigger should use `OLD` instead of `NEW`.

Answer (score 1):

why would you store this in a record?   Perhaps you should use 
Select COUNT(Student_Id) from Students Where Class_Id = @Class_Id

Comment: If you ever need to query for the top 10 classes by student count (and the number of classes is very large), you'd have a pretty heavy table scan query going on. If the database is heavily used, this query could impact overall performance during its execution.

Having the counter (and an index on the counter) makes this query far quicker and less disruptive on a busy database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON ENROLLMENT
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE CLASS SET NO_OF_STUDENTS = NO_OF_STUDENTS + 1 WHERE CLASS_NO = NEW.CLASS_NO;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: why is BEFORE not AFTER??? and why you dont use OLD instead of NEW? can you explain it to me please?!